# One table access much bigger than original files

Tags: ms-access

I have 12 excel files which are around 400 MB in total. But when importing them into access have already reached the 2 GB limit in the file 9.... is it normal?

Have tried to clean and compact but reduced only to 1.8 GB...

I do not have any query or report, just a big plain table (2.2 MM records x 30 columns so far).

If it is like that, as a solution do you think the options below would work?

1) Link to excel instead of importing it would reduce the file size considerably?
2) I can normalize the table a bit reducing some records by creating tables with the fields that are very repetitive

Thanks for any ideas...

(I could try the above by try and error but it would take me more than a coupe hours)

Comment: Check the field types in your imported table(s). By default, numbers imported to Access from Excel get stored as `Double` even if they are actually just integer values. Each `Double` value requires 8 bytes. If you can import them as `Long Integer` then they only need 4 bytes per value (1/2 the space of a `Double` holding the same value), or for smaller integers `Integer` values only need 2 bytes per value (1/4 the space of a `Double` holding the same value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking - if possible - is much to prefer.

xlsx files are zipped. Rename it to zip, open it and study the size of the main file in folder xl\worksheets.

Comment: Good point re: .xlsx files being compressed, so their size on disk may greatly underestimate their uncompressed size. (Actually, I have noticed that you have been making a lot of good contributions to the site lately. Thanks!) However, linking may involve a significant trade-off in performance because linked Excel tables have no indexes so queries against them could involve a lot of table scans.